# Move Javascript Object within Multidimensional Array / Object By ID or Path?

Tags: javascript, json, multidimensional-array

I am working on a new kind of drag and drop nestable menu admin that uses JSON as it's source data and always rebuilds from JSON, rather than hoping that the `.serialize()` functions people keep using will work.

Here is a link to where I am at: https://codepen.io/ajhalls-the-selector/pen/qBaPRyr

I have a couple helper functions that get me some of what I need from the events. I need to be able to move, or copy, elements (including all sub elements) to a new destination. The copy part was easy, but the move proved more challenging, so I was looking for some help.

If I drag `Harry` to `Gwen`, I will want the `Harry` to be nested under `Gwen`. By using the callbacks, I know the id of each element, I can also get back the path for each using the `findPath` function, but then how to move it?

Using the `moveJson()` function, I can easily add the item to the new location, but I can't seem to find how to delete the original.

```
function moveJson( Path, NewItem){
    
    eval(Path).children.push(NewItem); // this works to copy
    delete NewItem;
    eval(delete NewItem); //also tried
    delete eval(NewItem); // and this
}
moveJson('jsonData[0]["children"][1]["children"][0]',jsonData[1]);
```

I have tried a number of ways to pass the variables in using strings, or not, and multiple ways to delete. I have tried creating new objects to return instead of modifying the global. I tried flattening it, then moving it while flattened, and unflattening, but the `string.includes()` doesn't work when you give it strings with brackets.

Any tips for a simpler way of relocating an object using it's ID, or using it's absolute path?

As a side note, I realize `eval()` is discouraged, but not sure yet a better way of keeping things extremely dynamic. Since I don't know how deeply nested this dataset may get, working with the string result from `findPath` was nice and easy.

Here is the data I was working with:

```
var jsonData = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "parent_id": "0",
    "capacity": 2,
    "name": "Alan",
    "group": "BootstrapGlyphicon",
    "code": "",
    "prefix": "",
    "modifier": "",
    "custom": "",
    "sortorder": null,
    "status": "INACTIVE",
    "ui": {
      "draggable": "true",
      "ondragstart": "dragstart_handler(event);",
      "ondragend": "dragend_handler(event);",
      "ondrop": "drop_handler(event);",
      "ondragover": "dragover_handler(event);"
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "parent_id": "1",
        "capacity": 2,
        "name": "Samantha",
        "group": "BootstrapGlyphicon",
        "code": "",
        "prefix": "",
        "modifier": "",
        "custom": "",
        "sortorder": null,
        "status": "INACTIVE",
        "ui": {
          "draggable": "true",
          "ondragstart": "dragstart_handler(event);",
          "ondragend": "dragend_handler(event);",
          "ondrop": "drop_handler(event);",
          "ondragover": "dragover_handler(event);"
        },
        "children": [{
            "id": "5",
            "parent_id": "3",
            "capacity": 2,
            "name": "Harry",
            "group": "BootstrapGlyphicon",
            "code": "",
            "prefix": "",
            "modifier": "",
            "custom": "",
            "sortorder": null,
            "status": "INACTIVE",
            "ui": {
              "draggable": "true",
              "ondragstart": "dragstart_handler(event);",
              "ondragend": "dragend_handler(event);",
              "ondrop": "drop_handler(event);",
              "ondragover": "dragover_handler(event);"
            },
            "children": []
          },{
            "id": "7",
            "parent_id": "3",
            "capacity": 2,
            "name": "Pepper",
            "group": "BootstrapGlyphicon",
            "code": "",
            "prefix": "",
            "modifier": "",
            "custom": "",
            "sortorder": null,
            "status": "INACTIVE",
            "ui": {
              "draggable": "true",
              "ondragstart": "dragstart_handler(event);",
              "ondragend": "dragend_handler(event);",
              "ondrop": "drop_handler(event);",
              "ondragover": "dragover_handler(event);"
            },
            "children": []
          }]
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "parent_id": "1",
        "capacity": 2,
        "name": "Charlie",
        "group": "BootstrapGlyphicon",
        "code": "",
        "prefix": "",
        "modifier": "",
        "custom": "",
        "sortorder": null,
        "status": "INACTIVE",
        "ui": {
          "draggable": "true",
          "ondragstart": "dragstart_handler(event);",
          "ondragend": "dragend_handler(event);",
          "ondrop": "drop_handler(event);",
          "ondragover": "dragover_handler(event);"
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "id": 4,
            "parent_id": "3",
            "capacity": 2,
            "name": "Gwen",
            "group": "BootstrapGlyphicon",
            "code": "",
            "prefix": "",
            "modifier": "",
            "custom": "",
            "sortorder": null,
            "status": "INACTIVE",
            "ui": {
              "draggable": "true",
              "ondragstart": "dragstart_handler(event);",
              "ondragend": "dragend_handler(event);",
              "ondrop": "drop_handler(event);",
              "ondragover": "dragover_handler(event);"
            },
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "parent_id": "3",
            "capacity": 2,
            "name": "David",
            "group": "BootstrapGlyphicon",
            "code": "",
            "prefix": "",
            "modifier": "",
            "custom": "",
            "sortorder": null,
            "status": "INACTIVE",
            "ui": {
              "draggable": "true",
              "ondragstart": "dragstart_handler(event);",
              "ondragend": "dragend_handler(event);",
              "ondrop": "drop_handler(event);",
              "ondragover": "dragover_handler(event);"
            },
            "children": []
          }
];
```

Comment: One way to avoid using eval is to build out your own data structure which will show to step by step of navigating your json object. `{ property: "children", nextProperty: { property: 1 } } `

Comment: I am not sure how what you said helps. My data structure is all defined, but it is also highly dynamic. I will reuse this to build calendars, forms, database queries, so the only static things in the list would be the `id`, `parent_id`, `capacity`, and the `ui` element. All other properties would vary from use to use.