# Getting String Value of Parameter Used in Javascript Function when Parameter is Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, multidimensional-array

I want to get the string value of the `NewItem` object that is being passed.

```
function moveJson( Path, NewItem){ 
    eval(Path).children.push(eval("NewItem")); // makes a copy of NewItem at the Path location
    eval("delete "+ NewItem); // this is the tricky part
}

moveJson('jsonData[0]["children"][1]["children"][0]',jsonData[1]);  // Doesn't work
moveJson('jsonData[0]["children"][1]["children"][0]', 'jsonData[1]' );  // Works
```

How can I convert `NewItem` to the string `jsonData[1]` rather than `'[object Object]'`? When I pass the parameter in as a string, it will work, but I think it is cleaner if I can pass it in as the regular object reference.

I would prefer to migrate away from `eval` where possible, but haven't found a good way to accomplish this same thing without.

I would love it if I could pass it in like this:

```
function moveJson( Path, NewItem){ 
    NewItem = "'" + NewItem + "'";
    Path.children.push(eval(NewItem)); 
    eval("delete "+ NewItem); // this is the tricky part
}

moveJson(jsonData[0]["children"][1]["children"][0] ,jsonData[1]);
```

Trouble has been deleting the old data, which works if I pass it in as a string, but I haven't found another way.

Comment: Why would you need to pass "jsonData[1]" as a string in a function? And if you're passing it as a string it's going to be a static value.

Comment: I don't want to pass it as a string, but to delete it from it's original location, I haven't found a way to do it any other way. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65417675/move-javascript-object-within-multidimensional-array-object-by-id-or-path It is a highly dynamic enviroment

Comment: Yes. I have seen it. I'd suggest you use a recursive function to figure out the elements and the path dynamically instead of what you're doing.

Comment: Any example you can share? It blows my mind that with how mature JSON data is, and javascript objects, that there isn't a simple way to move something.